# How to use WorldEdit with high data values

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-worldedit

When using WorldEdit with modded Minecraft, I'll often run into the error:

```
Invalid data value 'x'
```

with `x` being a high number.
For example, when trying to paste in some HS Track from Railcraft: `[502:816]` - I'll get the error:

```
Invalid data value '816'
```

I've also tried using the BlockId I got from Minetweaker with `/mt hand` but got the same error (because this fixed it for another person). I used the BlockId `Railcraft:track:816`. I really just need a way to do this so if it is easier to use another mod please let me know.

Comment: Which Minecraft version are you playing in?

Comment: Minecraft 1.7.10 [forge version 10.13.4.1614-1.7.10]

Comment: To close voters: This is NOT technical support, it is about the usage of the mod itself. It's honestly getting annoying how often on-topic (and potentially good) modded Minecraft questions get downvoted and close-voted for no reason.